# How to fix a Android Compilation Error in Genexus?

Tags: android, sdk, genexus

When I try to run the web panel compilated for android I get this error:

> error: The following components of the Android SDK are either missing or do not meet their required version:

- Android 5.0 (API 21) ARM EABI v7a System Image (Any revision)
  Please go to 'Tools' > 'Update Android SDK' to install the latest Android requirements.
  Failed: Android Compilation
  Failed: Run Panel1An.

But I have this requirement already installed. What can I do to resolve this?

I tried to Run this solution

> Step 1- Open powershell cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools
>
> Step 2- run this command in powershell android.bat update sdk --no-ui

and I obtained this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
> ... 5 more

Comment: Did you run  'Tools' > 'Update Android SDK' on Genexus?

Comment: Yes, i did I resolved the problem by using another sdk. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Open powershell
`cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools`

Step 2- run this command in powershell
`android.bat update sdk --no-ui`

Comment: thanks  for the answer, I edited the question with an error that I got. Do you have some idea about what it is?

Comment: Go to C:\java and run "java -classpath . mainFunctionName", Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks, but finnally I resolved the problem by installing a new sdk